# Can P(X*Y >1 | Y > 1) be reduced?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, I'm curious if we can reduce $P(XY > 1|Y>1)$. Specifically, in this case $X$ is either 1 or -1 with a P(X=1) =.5 and P(x=-1)=.5. I know that if we have $P(XY > 1|Y=1)= P(1*X > 1)$, but I'm unsure if there is an appropriate reduction here. Logically, it becomes $P(X=1)* P(Y>1)$, but I'm unsure if that would suffice as a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ can only take values 1 and -1, then when $Y>1$, $XY$ is larger than 1 only if $X=1$. Then $P(XY>1|Y>1)=P(X=1|Y>1)$. If they are independent, then $P(X=1|Y>1)=P(X=1)=0.5$.